# How to Install ezdxf file for Anaconda\Spyder version

Tags: anaconda, ezdxf

I have used ezdxf module in python 2.4. Please guide some procedure for installing ezdxf in spyder verison 4.

Answer (score 0):

Run This command in the Anaconda CMD.exe prompt

conda install -c conda-forge ezdxf

#This command will show the latest version available list for your install or not. By <y/n)

Comment: ezdxf dropped Python 2 support in v0.9 (current version is v0.16) and ezdxf was **never** tested with Python < 2.7

Comment: I have worked with ezdxf V0.9 in python 2.4 previously. Presently, I am working on python 3.8 using ezdxf v0.16. I need syntax for "leader" using ezdxf